# Firebase realtime database can't insert (using Hashmap)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

I tried many times to insert the register data by hashmap into firebase realtime database, but only the authentication one is success. The `addOnCompleteListener` behind the `setValue()` didn't be trigger at all. The intent didn't start. Does anyone know how to fix with?

```
 private void register(String user_name, String email, String txt_password, String txt_mobile, String gender) {
  progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, txt_password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
      @Override
      public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
          if(task.isSuccessful()) {
              FirebaseUser rUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
              assert rUser != null;

              String userId = rUser.getUid();
              databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userId);
              HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
              map.put("userId", userId);
              map.put("username", user_name);
              map.put("email", email);
              map.put("mobile", txt_mobile);
              map.put("gender", gender);
              map.put("imageURL", "default");
              databaseReference.push().setValue(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                  @Override
                  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                      progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                      if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                          Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "註冊成功", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                          intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                          startActivity(intent);
                      } else {
                          Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  }
              });
          }
          else{
              progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }


      }
  });
}
```

My realtime database rule is

```
{"rules": {
  "Users":{
      "$user_id":{
        ".write":"$user_id === auth.uid && auth !== null",
        ".read":"$user_id === auth.uid && auth !== null"
      }
    }
    
  }
}
```

Comment: If you created your database in a non-default region, it could be that you downloaded the `google-services.json` before the database was created. If that is the case, you can solve it by specifying the database URL in your code in `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("database URL here").getReference()...`

Comment: Does Frank van Puffelen's suggestion solve your problem?  Please respond with @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The way definitely solve the problem. Thanks for your help.